# Swift Firebase iOS didReceiveRemoteNotification never calling

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I'm using Firebase in my iOS app and Azure Notification Hub on server to send notifications.
I've made all the needed things as in [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client) and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive) articles.
Here is my AppDelegate.swift code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self

      let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
      let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
      UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self

    return true
}
```

After this I'm calling a server side to register my application for notifications in Azure Notification Hub. Here is how I'm getting device token:

```
InstanceID.instanceID().instanceID { (result, error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("Error fetching remote instance ID: \(error)")
      } else if let result = result {
        let appGuid = KeychainService.loadAppGuid()
        let type = "apns"
        var str = "native.initClient('" + appGuid!
        str += "',  '" + AppName
        str += "', '\(type)', "
        str += "'\(result.token )'"
        str += ", '" + HUBNAME + "')"
        print(str)
        self.webViewController.callJavaScript(command: str)
      }
    }
```

And here is how I'm trying to receive notification in my AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
  let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
  if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
  }
  print(userInfo)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                 fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
  let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"
  if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
    print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
  }
  print(userInfo)
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
}
```

But none of these methods are called. Push notification certificates, identifiers and profiles are correct and valid. I run this code on Xcode Simulator. Why it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a real device to test push notification.

Comment: @siakdeta are you sure about that? Is there any way to test it with Xcode simulator?